# Is there any way possible to ask legit Adult based questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

Just after SO dropped out of BETA, I asked an *Adult* related question which got deleted.

I'm not going to ask the same question here (it got deleted for a point, right!) but but was asking a question about the adult industry with regards to servers and hosting and stuff. It wasn't naming any companies or products or stuff or pictures or links or anything.

It's a question for ServerFault, but SF didn't exist.

So .. if that got deleted, how can someone ask legit questions about adult related material with regards to programming or hosting or servers or whatnot?

Especially when it's not trying to show NSFW stuff or links to NSFW or illegal stuff.

Same goes with Gambling. There's a great post somewhere (did the SO krew do a podcast on this even?) -- the apparent shady side to our industry. It might be shady to some, but to others it's a legit and legal business model with legit clients.

Is there room in the StackExchange trilogy/quad-rilogy to ask these questions without offending some conservative people?

#### Update

Cheers for all the answers: asked the question on SF [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/42819/looking-for-some-advice-for-adult-web-hosting-solutions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't bother trying the 'nsfw' tag.  It won't fly.  Most of us use Stack Overflow at work, as it is designed, so there's not point in introducing the tag.
2. There's no reason you can't ask **technical** questions about running an adult site, whether it's hosting pornography or gambling.  Just leave the NSFW stuff out of your question.  If your questions are about hosting large amounts of video, streaming live video from a web-cam, or making lots of credit card transactions online, and someone figures out what you're doing, it still isn't grounds to close the question.  (Even if you're asking technical questions directly about computing winning poker hands or something related, I'd say that's still fine.  Just no overtly offensive stuff.)
3. Your question probably got closed because it belonged on SF, and as you said, at the time there was no SF.  I wouldn't try to read too much in to it.

Comment: Thanks bill - it's was 100% a technical based question ... it was actually asking about where to can someone host an adult and/or gambling site. It's very SF based IMO. I thought it was deleted because it was about the adult site stuff. I might try asking the question again on SF. I'll hopefully get a moderator to quickly view it to make sure it hasn't crossed the line. But yeah, there was no NSFW text/images/etc in the original question. Thanks Bill!

Comment: You're welcome.  It sounds like something the folks over at SF should be able to help with.  Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

Can you ask it in a way that's content-agnostic?  Most technical problems should be independent from the content.  e.g. image hosting, video streaming, credit card processing, age verification, text/video chat, etc.  None of those care what the content is.

Comment: that's EXACTLY what i did.... !!!! :(

Comment: If that's what you did, how did people know it was adult?

Comment: sorry. when u said cnontent-agnostic, i thought u were implying that it had nothing offensive or rude at all ... but of course that's not right. you ment that the content had no mention about specific genres, etc. at all. Unfortunatley, i had to as the question with explicit reference to the adult industry, otherwise i wouldn't have required the question :) So I don't think it's possible to as the question. Alternatively, maybe we could create a fake question and see how we could ask it in an agnostic way to not upset those conservatives?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I don't think it has anything to do with being conservative...  liberal.... etc....  Post a question with class that is not offensive and you'll get good results from lots of different folks....

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the industry that you would be asking the question for would have technical differences compared to others...  Why does the industry matter?

Remove all references to the type of industry and generalize your question to the point that people will not know if you are asking for the US Gov't, Dell, Microsoft, ESPN, etc....

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would require for you to analyze you question and boil it down in such a form that all association with adult-topics are lost, since then it's no longer a problem and hopefully your question will be a lot clearer (and more useful for other users).

But if you don't show NSFW stuff and your question is ServerFault-ish, why wouldn't it fit in there?

Perhaps give a small example?

Comment: I can't really, unless i actually ask the question again. Is it possible to find it in the creative-commons dump? You see, I'm not sure where the grey line is, even on Meta.SO.com ... like .. if i post some hard example here, then won't that just get this thread deleted?

So yeah .. i'm trying to see what some of the community thinks about this. Maybe it's time I ask the question again, now that SF is up.. ??? And if we all agree to some mature tags and keywords. ????

Answer (score 1):

personally, i think that if the question was as you described (i.e. had no adult content in itself, just happened to be about servers/software for adult sites) then the fact that the technology was for the "adult industry" was completely irrelevant - it was a perfectly legitimate question, should NOT have been deleted, and you should not have been penalised 100 points for asking it.

in fact, i'm quite disturbed that that even happened.   i can certainly see a need to keep adult content itself off SO/SF but technical questions about servers and software shouldn't be banned just because someone is offended by the mere concept of an adult industry.

subjective and personal moral judgements like that should be left out of here.

e.g. i saw a post on SF today where someone clearly from the telemarketing industry was asking a question about asterisk.  I personally find that far more offensive and immoral than any "adult" content but if we go around banning that because I don't like it and adult-server tech questions because someone else doesn't like it, then pretty soon the entire site will be empty because if there's one thing you can guarantee about **ANY** topic it is that someone, somewhere will manage to be offended by it.

censorship is evil.

(illegal content - e.g. asking for help with a warez site or worse - is another story....but even that's a huge grey area because what's illegal in one jurisdiction is perfectly legal in another)