# Work appropriate Stack Exchange ads on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, site-promotion

So I'm at work ... doing work things.  Like many of you I like to keep stack overflow up as a resource.  My boss walks up behind me and we have a quick conversation.  I notice he keeps glancing at my screen.  I don't check what he's looking at because I know whats up.  VS2010 and stack-overflow.

It wasn't until he left my cube that I noticed in giant bold letters stack exchange is prompting me about a question from the English Language and Usage Stack Exchange site site.

**[What is the word for the high-pitched "sex sound" a woman makes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51304/what-is-the-word-for-the-high-pitched-sex-sound-a-woman-makes)**

My boss is not familiar with Stack Overflow.  But he's pretty sure I'm not using my internet for work related stuff anymore.  So, on to the question.  How do I get rid of random Stack Exchange teaser questions or at least limit them to appropriate questions that don't make me look like a perv in front of the guy who signs my paycheck.

Comment: My initial reaction was to downvote and say "not our problem if your boss is unable to understand it's an ad". But on second thought, there is *some* merit to this - although I don't see a sane solution for it. Also, you're *extremely* likely to run into much worse on any ad-driven tech help site like W3schools (yuck). What if your boss sees you on a site that displays a lingerie ad?

Comment: As a lousy workaround, ad-blocking software will do.

Comment: That question was actually from the English Language & Usage site, [Sex.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/human-sexual-response-and-non-platonic-relations) is still at about 80% commitment and hasn't launched yet.

Comment: This (or something _very_ similar involving ads) has been brought up before. I'll try and find it.

Comment: @Fabian... funny.  Thanks for the clarification.  It was still embarrassing but I'm cooling off now.  I'm sure in an hour I'll even be able to laugh about it.

Comment: Found it, and this one was actually an (awful) ad for software. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105682/is-the-plastic-scm-ad-on-stack-overflow-appropriate-for-a-professional-website

Comment: I assumed it was a sex related site because I've seen other prompts about "sex and non platonic relations" or something like that.

Comment: There was another question about inappropriate questions in the hot question list, but I can't find it now

Comment: @MichaelMrozek perhaps this is it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105682/is-the-plastic-scm-ad-on-stack-overflow-appropriate-for-a-professional-website, also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85932/how-do-i-report-an-advertisement-seen-on-a-stackexchange-site-as-offensive

Comment: [From July 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/151211) : "Don't bother trying the 'nsfw' tag. It won't fly. Most of us use Stack Overflow at work, as it is designed, so there's not point in introducing the tag." - Bill the Lizard ♦. I wonder if it's time for things to change?

Comment: Isn't your rep high enough to hide ads?

Comment: @Purmou High rep doesn't hide ads for A51 proposals (or any side ads), only the inline ones over questions and between answers.

Comment: @Fezziwig, it was [just yesterday by a new user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115717/how-can-i-stop-adds-on-my-right-side-specially-when-it-shows-those-words-sex), it got zapped as a dupe of this one

Comment: You might send your boss a link to this question...before your boss sends HR to you...

Comment: I surreptitiously brought it up in a conversation a couple days later and he laughed it off - with a - hey it's the internet... things happen.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, while I was reading this question a female coworker walked up behind me.
Notice the words that are bolded?

Anyway, I think internal site ads should have links below them that let you flag them for moderator attention. This is already implemented when it comes to the questions and answers on this site, so it would already be familiar behavior.

As to what the moderators could do, if they review the ad and find it objectionable, they could approve the flag so that the ad is taken out of circulation.

After that, Chaos has to review it to put it back in circulation.

That's what Chaos is for, right?

Comment: If I remember correctly the bolding and the link came after someone edited my question. :)